# How to statically link libjpeg to xCode project

Tags: xcode, libjpeg

I'm trying to work with libjpeg and I need to statically link it to my xCode project. I'm a complete beginner so I don't know where to start. 
I have xCode v4.5, Mac OX 10.8. 
Any help??